# JSR 303 - Validate a field if it is not null

Tags: validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, jsr

I have a form which is filled in, and some of the fields are options. I want to apply validations on the information that was filled in but the optional fields should be validated only if there was something filled in, so if theses are not null. Did any of you do something similar?
Or do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Bean Validation constraints usually accept `null` as valid value (with the exception of `@NotNull` of course). Depending on your UI framework you might retrieve empty strings instead of null for fields without user input. If you're are working with JSF 2, you can set the context parameter `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` to `false` to avoid a validation of empty fields.